# Can't bind TCP listener *:6379 using Redis on Windows

Tags: redis

I'm using Redis 2.8 on Windows which I downloaded from github release. After unzip and I've set maxheap in `redis.windows.conf` file. After running `redis-server redis.windows.conf` I get `# Creating  Server TCP listening socket *:6379:No such file or directory`, but redis is not running correctly. I don't know why.

Comment: Now service is normally.I run `redis-cli.exe` in the same window,and it  connect correctly.Then I typed `shutdown`,the service is over.Reopen a command windows,type `redis-server`.The service run correctly.But I still did not understand why `# Creating  Server TCP listening socket *:6379:No such file or directory` came out.

Comment: I ran into the same problem this morning on Win 2008 R2. Your comment worked so you should post and accept it as the answer :)

Comment: @verbumSapienti OK,I'll post the answer.

Comment: you can accept it with the tick to the left of the answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Now service is normally.I run `redis-cli.exe` in the same window,and it connect correctly.Then I typed shutdown,the service is over.Reopen a command windows,type `redis-server`.The service run correctly.But I still did not understand why `# Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379:No such file or directory` came out.

Comment: nope. When I run redis-cli.exe, I see a black screen. Can't even type. So change the port to 6380 and it worked !

Comment: "But I still did not understand why # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379:No such file or directory came out." - because you had a Redis server running as a windows service. Your shutdown command stopped it.

Alternatively you can go into Computer Management > Services and Applications > Services and stop Redis and set it to not start automatically at startup.

Answer (score 103):

You must've used the .msi installer. It automagically registers a windows service which starts instantly after the installation (at least on my win 10 machine).

This service uses the default config and binds to port 6379. When you start redis-server from the command line, if you haven't specified a different port through a config file, it picks up the default config again and tries to bind to port 6379 which fails.

Your cli works because it connects to the redis service that's already listening on 6379. Your shutdown command stops the service and from there things work as expected. Mystery solved. Case closed.

Comment: perfect answer.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: That's nice to hear from a SexyBeast. My life is complete ;)

Comment: If you want to completely remove running Redis as a service, on windows: 
Windows key (Run) > Regedit > "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/Redis" > right mouse click > delete

Comment: Great answer! This helped alot. I thought there was a problem but turns out it isn't a problem. Just needed to know this.

Answer (score 78):

`cd`to the bin directory of Redis, and run

1. redis-cli.exe
2. shutdown
3. exit

open another cmd window, `cd` to the bin directory of Redis, and run

4.redis-server.exe

Comment: A few words of explanation would make this more helpful.

Comment: You are an angel. Thank you!

Comment: It worked even if it said that server was not running

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 10):

We had a similar/related "redis-server.exe" service hosting issue.

After installing the Redis Windows Service, we could access the service on port 6379 locally, but not from a remote client (even though the firewall was configured to allow inbound traffic on the port).

In order to resolve the issue, we had to edit the **redis.windows-service.conf** configuration file and change the following:

- `bind 127.0.0.1` needed use the actual IP address
- `protected-mode yes` needed to be set to "no"

After making the above changes, we restarted the Redis service and were able to connect from all clients.

Comment: This solved my problem. This probably is the answer if: everything (including firewall, server, etc) is configure properly, and accessible from same host, but not from other host.

Answer (score 8):

Its simple and works for me nice:
-open `redis-cli` (default in `C:\Program Files\Redis`) and run this command:

> shutdown

Finished.

now open `cmd` and try `redis-server` again.

I know its a little late for answering but because maybe others faced this problem later I answered it.

Answer (score 3):

After getting this error,open the cli and press the command 'shutdown' and restart redis server. You are good to go. You will get the logo and everything is as expected.

Answer (score 2):

1. check the port(if something else is using redis port)
2. use `redis-server xxx.conf` to run a server with your configuration
3. try to use `redis-cli`
4. check redis issues(https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows/wiki/Issues-might-happen)

   C:\redis>redis-server.exe --service-install [8124] 03 Feb 23:58:14.573 # HandleServiceCommands: system error caught. error c ode=1073, message = CreateService failed: unknown error

   C:\redis>redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose [10848] 04 Feb 00:00:40.508 # HandleServiceCommands: system error caught. error code=1073, message = CreateService failed: unknown error

   C:\redis>redis-server --service-install -–service-name redisService1 –port 100 01 Failed to open the .conf file: 10001 CWD=C:\redis

   C:\redis>redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf -–service-name redis Service1 –port 10001 Failed to open the .conf file: 10001 CWD=C:\redis

   C:\redis>redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf -–service-name redis Service1 –port 10001 Failed to open the .conf file: 10001 CWD=C:\redis

   C:\redis>redis-server --service-install C:\redis\redis.windows.conf -–service-n ame redisService1 –port 10001 Failed to open the .conf file: 10001 CWD=C:\redis

   C:\redis>redis-server --service-install C:\redis\redis.windows.conf -–service-n ame redisService1 –port 10001 Failed to open the .conf file: 10001 CWD=C:\redis

   C:\redis>redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf -–service-name redis Service1 –port 10001 Failed to open the .conf file: 10001 CWD=C:\redis

   C:\redis> C:\redis>redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf -–service-name redis Service1 –port 10001 Failed to open the .conf file: 10001 CWD=C:\redis

   C:\redis>redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose [11572] 04 Feb 00:03:34.847 # HandleServiceCommands: system error caught. error code=1073, message = CreateService failed: unknown error

   C:\redis>redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose -- service-name redisService [7484] 04 Feb 00:03:53.610 # Granting read/write access to 'NT AUTHORITY\Network Service' on: "C:\redis" "C:\redis" [7484] 04 Feb 00:03:53.612 # Redis successfully installed as a service.

Answer (score -1):

Got the same behavior after restart. Initially thought Redis is not running, but your question made me to dig some more. Apparently, there's Windows service, called "Redis" and it started after computer reboot.

Answer (score -1):

I just got the same error message, but the root cause was different: I copied the config file over from a different machine, but it contained a "bind" entry containing an IP address, which - for sure - was invalid for the new machine,
i.e. bind 234.234.234.234

I changed it to the correct address and it was working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

As @FeigMan said you must've used the .msi installer. It automagically registers a windows service which starts instantly after the installation.

I was getting below error:

[15052] 10 Apr 14:40:14.601 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: listen: Unknown error

If service is already running you will get above error.
As per need you can restart service by below commands:

redis-server --service-stop
redis-server --service-start

Answer (score -1):

For windows after installing using windows installer. So Check if your Redis server is already up and running.
check by going to redis-cli

> redis-cli
> 127.0.0.1:6379>