# ASP.net app connection REDIS SocketFailure on Ping

Tags: asp.net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I just installed the REDIS server in one of my development servers. And i am trying to connect my localhost application with this external server. I am using StackExchange.REDIS api to make the connection to this REDIS server located at my internal development server 10.26.130.170. I installed the REDIS software with everything default, and made no customization's so far.

Here is the connection class from my project ::

```
  public sealed class RedisSingleton
{
    private static Lazy<ConfigurationOptions> configOptions = new Lazy<ConfigurationOptions>(() =>
                 {
                     var configOptions = new ConfigurationOptions();   
                     configOptions.EndPoints.Add("10.26.130.170:6379");
                     configOptions.ClientName = "MyAppRedisConn";
                     configOptions.ConnectTimeout = 100000;
                     configOptions.SyncTimeout = 100000;
                     configOptions.AbortOnConnectFail = true;                         
                     return configOptions;
                 });

    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyRedisconn = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(
                                                                                                    () => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configOptions.Value));

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer ActiveRedisInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return LazyRedisconn.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Please advise on some suggestions. Is there a way i can quickly check in my localhost and verify the connection reach to the REDIS server at the port 6379 using ping or some other command.

The 6379 port is not open on the remote server of redis. I found it with the help of the windows **PortQueryUI** tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by opening the port at the remote server.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164691/86023